# Getting an Exception from an Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have received an error log that shows the following code threw the exception in set

```
  public double Value {
        get {
            switch (DefinedUnits.Distance) {
                case DistanceUnits.Feet: { return Feet; }
                case DistanceUnits.Meters: { return Meters; }
                case DistanceUnits.NM: { return NauticalMiles; }
                default: { throw new Exception("Invalid Distance Unit Specified"); }
            }
        }
        set {
            switch (DefinedUnits.Distance) {
                case DistanceUnits.Feet: { Feet = value; break; }
                case DistanceUnits.Meters: { Meters = value; break; }
                case DistanceUnits.NM: { NauticalMiles = value; break; }
                default: { throw new Exception("Invalid Distance Unit Specified"); }
            }
        }
    }
```

DefinedUnits.Distance is an enum:

```
public enum DistanceUnits {
        Meters,
        Feet,
        NM
    }
```

There is no way I can see in my code that something else can be sent.  I have no place where this enum is treated as an integer so that a bad value could be passed in. The user cannot tell me what he was doing.  Or rather he tells me he was doing something that could not have called this.

Is there a logical explanation for why this happened and how can I stop it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you pasted everything correctly? You use the enum as `DefinedUnits` but declared it as `DistanceUnits`.

Comment: Yes. DefinedUnits is a class. DefinedUnits defines different types of unit. Distance, Dimension, Coordinates. Distance if defined with Distance Units

Comment: @vcsjones: That's presumably fetching from a *property* called `DefinedUnits` - or a static property called `Distance` in a class called `DefinedUnits`.

Comment: The only way you cannot know how this exception was raised is when you don't log the exception's StackTrace property.  Fix that first.

Comment: @Hans I have the stack trace I know where it comes from. That is the basis for me asking. The value set in the enum DistanceUnits is set somewhere else via a settings dialog. The only explanation for it would be if the user manually entered bad data in the settings file and I do not think he did that. I just checked and the value in the log for the relevant value is a valid one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefinedUnits.Distance is either null or initialised to something out of range.

Changing your default handler should give you a clue:

`default: { throw new Exception("Invalid Distance Unit Specified: " + DefinedUnits.Distance != null ? DefinedUnits.Distance.ToString() : '**null**' ); }`

Comment: Fixed your code sample to properly handle nulls and conversion to string.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the value was fetched before it was ever set, leaving a default value which was invalid? (Admittedly if you haven't set any corresponding integers, `Meters` should correspond to 0...) You should adjust your code to:

- Throw a more specific exception (e.g. [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx))
- Include the value in the exception message

If you have the stack trace, you should at least be able to see whether it was the getter or the setter that was throwing the exception...

Comment: I have the stack trace and it is the setter.  And I know what called it and why

Comment: No the enum is not explicitly set with integers.  I will certainly do that.

Answer (score 0):

Print to the log Exception.StackTrace and (int)DefinedUnits.Distance value to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dotfuscator (or some other obfuscating software) and you convert string value (for instance "Feet") to enum, then it is possible that enum names were obfuscated and string-to-enum conversion fails.

Comment: Thanks but this is not obfuscated.